# How do I make plugins work in rhythmbox 2.99.1?

Tags: rhythmbox

I would like to use coverflow and an equalizer in rhythmbox. So I downloaded the fossfreedom plugins and installed those I needed, but how can I make them work when I don't have a toolbar with a plugin menu? I don't understan the following which is written in another post: "look to activate the plugin via a Tool menu option." Where can I find this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can I suggest you to [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/375167/edit) and link the page from where you got the plugin on from you got the quote?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins in newer versions of Rhythmbox can often activated through the Tool's menu option.

Pictures paint a thousand words...

- Lets enable a plugin - Hover you mouse at the top-panel and click Rhythmbox to show the menu

[image: pic]

- Click the Plugins menu and find your plugin.  Tick the checkbox to enable the plugin

[image: pic]

- Close the window and then move your mouse back to the top-panel and click Rhythmbox again

[image: pic]

Under the tools menu you will see options such as the Equalizer.

Since you mentioned the Coverart Browser plugin...

Enable the plugin in the same way as the Equalizer plugin above.

You will then see a new *source* which you can click on to reveal the coverart-browser

[image: pic]

Comment: So easy. Many thanks but now I have another problem: When trying to activate CoverArt Search a small window opens saying: "Conflicting plugin found. The ArtSearch plugin has been deactivated". Now I have CoverArt Browser without covers. Is there something I can do?

Comment: That really is another question - you need to download the covers.  This is explained in the wiki: https://github.com/fossfreedom/coverart-browser/wiki/How-to-find-great-coverart